# On branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean

Tags: github, git-commit

Why am I facing this error? I've done all the necessary steps. It still says:

> On branch master
>   nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: We definitely need more details. But it sounds like you have nothing to commit. What does "git status" show? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: You are not providing enough information about your problem. What you're seeing is completely normal if there is nothing to commit to the master branch. You need to be more explicit and provide more details or we will not be able to help you.

Comment: it is not an error, it is a message that displays when git has nothing to commit

Comment: git branch -u origin/master helped me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `git status`.

Make sure you have done:

```
git add .
git commit -m "add my files"
```

If those files are not added, see with `git check-ignore -v -- afile`, if said files are not ignored.

Comment: Is there a single command to stage aka `add` as well as `commit` all files ? 
Also, what if I want to `add .`  all files except the `README.md` , how would you perform this action ?

Comment: @Sumax [`git commit -am "commit all files"`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--a) does add *and* commit all files (it does not exclude one modified file). It is not considered a best practice, though. It is always best to check (git status) what you have added before committing.

Comment: 1. `git add` --> 2. `git status` --> 3. `git commit`